# Merge Only When Value is Empty/Null in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes in Pandas which are being merged together df.A and df.B, df.A is the original, and df.B has the new data I want to bring over.  The merge works fine and as expected I get two columns col_x and col_y in the merged df.

However, in some rows, the original df.A has values where the other df.B does not.  My question is, **how can I selectively take the values from col_x and col_y and place them into a new col such as col_z ?**

Here's what I mean, how can I merge df.A:

```
date   impressions    spend    col
1/1/15 100000         3.00     ABC123456
1/2/15 145000         5.00     ABCD00000
1/3/15 300000         15.00    (null)
```

with df.B

```
date    col
1/1/15  (null)
1/2/15  (null)
1/3/15  DEF123456
```

To get:

```
date   impressions    spend    col_z
1/1/15 100000         3.00     ABC123456
1/2/15 145000         5.00     ABCD00000
1/3/15 300000         15.00    DEF123456
```

Any help or point in the right direction would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Show your code which isn't working.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

OK assuming that your (null) values are in fact NaN values and not that string then the following works:

```
In [10]:
# create the merged df
merged = dfA.merge(dfB, on='date')
merged

Out[10]:
        date  impressions  spend      col_x      col_y
0 2015-01-01       100000      3  ABC123456        NaN
1 2015-01-02       145000      5  ABCD00000        NaN
2 2015-01-03       300000     15        NaN  DEF123456
```

You can use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas.Series.where) to conditionally assign a value from the _x and _y columns:

```
In [11]:
# now create col_z using where
merged['col_z'] = merged['col_x'].where(merged['col_x'].notnull(), merged['col_y'])
merged

Out[11]:
        date  impressions  spend      col_x      col_y      col_z
0 2015-01-01       100000      3  ABC123456        NaN  ABC123456
1 2015-01-02       145000      5  ABCD00000        NaN  ABCD00000
2 2015-01-03       300000     15        NaN  DEF123456  DEF123456
```

You can then [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop) the extraneous columns:

```
In [13]:

merged = merged.drop(['col_x','col_y'],axis=1)
merged

Out[13]:
        date  impressions  spend      col_z
0 2015-01-01       100000      3  ABC123456
1 2015-01-02       145000      5  ABCD00000
2 2015-01-03       300000     15  DEF123456
```

Comment: How can you merge multiple columns 

I am doing repeated tasks to get the final output but wonder if there is a cleaner way 



```
obs_table['value'] = obs_table['value_coded'].where(obs_table['value_coded'].notnull(),obs_table['value_numeric'])
obs_table['value'] = obs_table['value'].where(obs_table['value'].notnull(),obs_table['value_text'])
obs_table['value'] = obs_table['value'].where(obs_table['value'].notnull(),obs_table['value_datetime'])
obs_table['value'] = obs_table['value'].where(obs_table['value'].notnull(),obs_table['value_datetime'])
```

Answer (score 6):

IMO the shortest and yet readable solution is something like that:

```
df.A.loc[df.A['col'].isna(), 'col'] = df.A.merge(df.B, how='left', on='date')['col_y']
```

What it basically does is assigning values from merged table column `col_y` to primary `df.A` table, for those rows in `col` column, which are empty (`.isna()` condition).

Comment: very clean... thx!  to merge on multiple columns change the on=' ' to a list.

Comment: I don't think `df.A.merge()` will work because a Series doesn't have `.merge()`, only  a DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

If you have got data that contains 'nans' and you want to fill the 'nans'  from other dataframe
(that matching the index and columns names) you can do the following:

**df_A** : target DataFrame that contain nans element

**df_B** : the source DataFrame thatcomplete the missing elements

```
df_A = df_A.where(df_A.notnull(),df_B)
```