# python - merge/replace only when value is NaN for all multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm looking for a solution similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296798/merge-only-when-value-is-empty-null-in-pandas) but for multiple columns. So I have this `table1`:

```
date   client_id   product_id  date2   col2   col3
1/1/15 1           A           1/1/20  50     AAA
1/2/15 2           B           1/3/30  40     BBB
1/3/15 2           B           NaN     NaN    NaN
```

where I need to merge it with `table2`:

```
date   client_id   product_id  date3   col2  col3
1/1/15 1           A           1/1/20  1000   XXX
1/2/15 2           B           NaN     NaN    NaN
1/3/15 2           B           2/3/27  3000   ZZZ
```

Resulting with a `table1` like this (output expected):

```
date   client_id   product_id  date2   col2   col3
1/1/15 1           A           1/1/20   50     AAA
1/2/15 2           B           1/3/30   40     BBB
1/3/15 2           B           2/3/27   3000   ZZZ
```

The number of rows for `table1` and `table2` are the same, as the key columns (`date`, `client_id`, `product_id`) for both tables are the same. However, their main difference is on `date2`, `date3`. If `date2` is null, all the `col` columns will be null (from `col2` to `col500`), Same for `date3`. However, I need to replace where `date2` is null with values of `date3` given the key columns.

The solution in the link at the beginning creates an auxiliar column for each column you need to replace, but it's impractical for a dataset of 500 columns.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One quick way is to use `concat` and `groupby`:

```
(pd.concat([table1, table2.rename(columns={'date3':'date2'})])
   .groupby(['date','client_id'], as_index=False)
   .first()
)
```

Output:

```
     date  client_id product_id   date2    col2 col3
0  1/1/15          1          A  1/1/20    50.0  AAA
1  1/2/15          2          B  1/3/30    40.0  BBB
2  1/3/15          2          B  2/3/27  3000.0  ZZZ
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit? It keep the first of what? Should I include product_id also in group_by because it's one of the keys to merge?

Comment: Yes, I guess I didn’t read the question thoroughly. The idea is groupby can act like merge while first will ignore NaN and try to find the first valid values.